# A top content system written in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

I want to write a top articles system.

I want to filter some content (articles/etc..) by number of views.

If I insert in database with `views=views+1` every time when a user view that link, I think it's slowly and it's a bad practice.

An example of another site that does this is YouTube. It updates this table only at a certain interval, so the views aren't updated live. Is this a good practice to do this?

Comment: -1. No evidence of attempts. Being a help vampire. etc.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Isn't `views=views+1` an attempt? I think the OP is just looking for better ways to do this, which is actually a pretty good question...

Comment: @minitech the way it is written sounds like a thought. Not progress. In coding: `thought != progress`, but `flowchart == progress`

Comment: He definitely had the algorithm written in his brains, and not coded yet, so in the SDLC life cycle, he is probably gathering enough info before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: I know how to do that of course, but I want to do this in a better way!

I though to use memcache from PHP to store somehow the views count in RAM memory and after at an interval of time to insert it into database (maybe using a cron job).

I only need a new ideea of a new algorithm, I don't want code, I can implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a log (simple text file / xml / Json ………) to store the view count and do a job to parse the file and insert the result into the DB.

This job could run in time intervals or check the system for idle processor.

In my opinion, using the RAM to store sensitive data as this count (an important part of your system) seems kind of insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table of views; you can also use this second table to filter "duplicate" views (backed too by cookies - removing duplicate views won't be a perfect operation).

As for being "slow" I've used that approach on many sites with many users. Storing and aggregating data is what databases do, so use their power.

Then you can use this second table to total the views, or periodically sum up the data and store the running total in the main table, clearing out the second table to keep space down. I usually keep all the data but demoralize for speed.